# Trouble with finding part of a word

Tags: haskell

this was a 0 point question of our homework two weeks ago so please don't flip if it looks like homework.
What it is supposed to do is to find a String (in it's order) within another string.

```
isPart:: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPart [] _ = True
isPart _ [] = False
isPart (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y = moveone xs ys
    | otherwise = isPart (x:xs) ys

moveone:: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
moveone [] _ = True
moveone (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y = moveone xs ys
    | otherwise = isPart (x:xs) ys
```

so if I type isPart "house" "Treehouse" it should be true, but it shouldn't if I type    isPart "house" "Treheouse"

I am having the problem that once a Char is found to be equal it is removed from the list in moveone, so once the h is found the function will only look for "ouse"

I know I can't save a String, to return to it. Please don't solve it, simply give me ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. First you return `False` from `moveone` in case the characters differ.
2. Next, from `isPart` instead of simply calling `moveone` add an alternative:

   ```
       | x == y = (moveone xs ys) || isPart (x:xs) ys
   ```

Because matching can fail at any character, not only the first one.

As a side note, add a pattern alias for the x-list in `isPart`: `xList@(x:xs)`; otherwise you reconstruct the list for each recursive call. (Though your compiler might optimize it out.)